# reading form multiple serial ports at same time

Tags: mysql, vb.net, arduino, rfid

i am working on attendance system project based on data sent from RFID via arduino to VB.net through serial ports

```
 Private Sub connect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles connect.Click
    connect.Enabled = False
    disconnect.Enabled = True
    myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
    SerialPort1.PortName = myPort(0)
    'Set SerialPort1 to the selected COM port at startup
    SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
    'Set Baud rate to the selected value on
    'Other Serial Port Property
    SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
    SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
    SerialPort1.DataBits = 8            'Open our serial port
    Try                     ' Start of exception handling 
        If SerialPort1.IsOpen = True Then        ' Port has been opened 

            Exit Sub
        End If
        SerialPort1.Open()            ' Opens the port 
    Catch ex As Exception           ' Exception handling 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    SerialPort1.RtsEnable = True
    If Not TextBoxID.Text Is Nothing Then
        Timer2.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

how can i write code that help me to deal with two serial ports at same time ( serial send entrance data and one send exit data ) on the same vb project

Comment: I don't know VB, but in C# I'd just use non-blocking read calls and instantiate two serial port objects... The drivers will do the rest..

Comment: how could you do it plz  !! it may help me to find a similar code or i can find an idea

Comment: Did you manage to get data from one serial? What is `Timer2` for?